# Inaccurate masks with Mask-RCNN: Stairs effect and sudden stops

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-segmentation

I've been using matterport's Mask R-CNN to train on a custom dataset. However, there seem to be some parameters that i failed to correctly define because on practically all of the images, the bottom or top of the object's mask is cut off:
[image: innacurate prediction: mask is cut-off on the bottom]

As you can see, the bounding box is fine since it covers the whole blade, but the mask seems to suddenly stop in a horizontal line on the bottom.

On another hand, there is a stair-like effect on masks of larger and curvier objects such as this one (in addition to the bottom and top cut-offs):
[image]

- The original images are downscaled to `IMAGE_MIN_DIM = IMAGE_MAX_DIM = 1024` using the "square" mode.
- `USE_MINI_MASK` is set to true with `MINI_MASK_SHAPE = (512, 512)` (somehow if i set it off, RAM gets filled and training chrashes).
- `RPN_ANCHOR_SCALES = (64, 128, 256, 512, 1024)` since the objects occupy a large space of the image.

It doesn't feel like the problem comes from the amount of training. These two predictions come from 6 epochs of 7000 steps per epoch (took around 17 hours). And the problem appears from early stage and persists along all the epochs.

Any idea on what changes to make ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply how `Mask-RCNN` works, and is a known side effect. Nothing you can do implementation wise to make it not appear. [PointRend](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.08193.pdf) discusses the problem (proving that it's not just you), and also proposes their own algorithm (which is an extension to `Mask-RCNN`) to solve it. In the image below you can see an image from that paper. On the top left they ran Mask-RCNN on a 28x28 image, in which you can see the staircasing as well. The other images relate to how they solve it.

The bad news is of course that it's not easy to just slam the PointRend code onto Mask-RCNN, I at least don't know any great implementations. The PointRend [github](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/tree/master/projects/PointRend) itself also doesn't allow for any retraining on your own data.

[image: this]

EDIT:

For postprocessing, there's a lot of approaches you can take. How about this one:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I didn't know about PointRend. Although this is a known issue with Mask-RCNN, I still feel as if I haven't optimized my model well enough to reach the maximum potential there is. For example, in Figure 1 of the PointRend paper you linked, the mask on the left (which is from a Mask-RCNN model) feels more accurate than the masks i have. If there is no solution I am at least trying to optimize my results.

Comment: Like in some post processing step? I think for the blades of windturbines use case, mapping each point of the edge of the segmentation to the closest edge (using canny edge detection) might just do the trick. Sample the edge of the segmentation with say 500 points, calculate perpendicular lines to the segmentation mask, calculate the closest edge, and that's a new "segmentation edge point". Take the convex hull, and you are done

Comment: I have tried using canny edge detection but the results aren't very satisfying because of the variance in horizon shades, clouds, the presence of turbines in the background etc...

Comment: how about you start with the mask you have detected for a watershedding algorithm ?

Comment: You think i could get pixel-precision results ? This is the ultimate goal

Comment: with some smart post processing you for sure could. I added an idea in the answer. There's a lot of stuff you could still do

Comment: I have already tried post-processing with tools like opencv's erosion/dilatation, kmeans etc... But what i don't show here is that the images vary a lot. Size and shape of the blade, fields in the background, clouds, other turbines, are all varying and i need the segmentation to be fully automatic.

Comment: there's two paths then - just keep digging in the post processing world, or try implement PointRend on MaskRCNN. Up to you! I hope my answers were acceptable.